# Which access control module will allow me to use limit visibility of individual nodes?

Tags: 7, users

There are a ton of Access control modules. Choosing one is difficult. The current use case is that I have a single video content type. Some videos are public and some are private that are only accessible by role. I want to be able to set each node (public or private) and then ensure that they do not show in taxonomy term pages and views pages unless they are logged in. Which module is best for this use case? Note that the term and view pages will be the shared but I need private ones to automatically removed if they are not logged in. Which access control module will meet these needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BAM!

[Taxonomy Access Control](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) to the rescue.

Access control for user roles based on taxonomy categories (vocabulary, terms).

> Automatically controls access to nodes (based on their taxonomy
> terms).
>
> - Configuration page for each user role.
> - Three node access permission types: View, Update, Delete.
> - Two term access types: View tag, Add tag.

Just create a term called something like "Members only" and add that term reference to your video content types.

Comment: Will this automatically remove private videos from term pages generated by core? Will it also automatically remove them from views pages?

Comment: If the user doesn't have permissions to view the node, then it should hide it from all content lists.  That said, if query rewriting is on in the advanced setting for your view, then it will ignore access control.

Comment: yup that was the one. A confusing UI but worked like a hot damn. Thanks.